# KnexJS raw query not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have a query that's the following:

```
SET @count = 0; UPDATE table SET table.id = @count:= @count + 1 WHERE table.name = "name";
```

If I execute it through console, or something like Jetbrains Datagrip, it works perfectly, but when I push it through Knex as a raw query, it responds with a mysql ER_PARSE_ERROR.

I've done some testing, and it seems like Knex doesn't understand what @count is.

Any ideas? If it's possible to format this using Knex methods, I'd really appreciate the tips

Comment: Please post the knex code you use to execute the query.

Comment: `return knex.raw('SET @count = 0; UPDATE table SET table.id = @count:= @count + 1 WHERE table.name = "name";');`

Comment: Knex / driver does not support passing multiple statements to raw at once. If you really want to do it like this you can start transaction, run first `trx.raw('SET @count = 0')` and then `trx.raw('UPDATE table SET table.id = @count:= @count + 1 WHERE table.name = "name"')` and commit in the end.

Comment: The following transaction doesn't go through at all. No error output either

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can write this as a Knex.js query using transaction promises to increment `count` instead:

```
var count = 0;
knex.transaction(function(trx){
    knex('table')
        .where('name', '=', 'name')
        .update(({
            id: count
        });
})
.then(()=>++count);
```

Comment: This almost works. It goes through all the entries, but it doesn't increment the id. Just sets everything to 0.

Comment: Then remove `count` from the top of this block and put it at the top of all of your code as a global variable. That way it won't get reset every time you try to update.

Comment: Tried that, no change

Comment: Can you post your entire js file? You may want to look into auto increment generated numbers in SQL.

Comment: I mean it's pretty much what you've posted, just formatted slightly formatted

`sortIds(name) {
        var count = 0;
        return knex.transaction((trx) => {
            knex('table').where({name: name}).update({id: count});
        }).then(() => ++count);
}`

Comment: A few issues. Whether you write the function like you did or like I did, it's going to set `count` to 0. You can put the line `var count = 0` as a global, but it will still be reset when the app is restarted. The best bet would be to increment `id`, like this `UPDATE table SET id = id + 1` or similar in KnexJs.

Comment: I suppose it would be useful to mention what the goal behind this is. When I call a delete().where({}) query on this database, I'd like the database to automatically resort my ids so there aren't gaps in numbers. Problem is, if there each `name` entry in the table has it's own set of ids. So if there's `name`+`id` such as {x, 1}, {x, 2}, {x, 3}, an entry with `name`=`y` would start from 1, not 4

Comment: Yeesh. That sounds like a bad idea. You would have to do a massive update every time something is changed. Are you sure you want to do it this way and not just have something in the code itself?